# Java Swing смена типа JEditorPane на text/plain делает из кириллицы html коды символов

Tags: java, кодировка, swing, кириллица

Столкнулся со  сложностью создаю текстовое поле в Swing пишу в нем кириллицей.

```
JEditorPane area2 = new JEditorPane();
area2.setContentType("text/html;Charset=windows-1251");
area2.setText("Привет");
```

Отображается все хорошо

```
Привет
```

Потом меняю тип поля и записываю в него строку получаю не то

```
String text = area2.getText();
area2.setContentType("text/plain;Charset=UTF-8");
area2.setText(text);
```

Вижу буквы в виде HTML кода, с латиницей все нормально.

```
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    &#1055;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;
  </body>
</html>
```

Может есть мысли как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Зачем Вы поменяли кодировку на UTF-8, она ведь по факту не менялась?

Comment: Прости что ввел вас в заблуждение . Пример с такой кодировкой опубликовал по невнимательности пробовал решить эту проблему меняя кодировки.  Но переменная String text = area2.getText(); уже содержит вместо букв HTML код. До изменения кодировки. Можно не менять кодировку, от этого не чего не измениться . Я предполагаю что корни проблемы кроются тут javax.swing.text.html.parser

Comment: Да, верно, только не parser a [writer](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/d269ebbad2286b57802a075091b0cc32110dfcc7/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLWriter.java#L1260)

Comment: По пытался разобраться когда вызывается Writer.output искал в модели в представлении, прыгал отладчиком туда сюда, но так и не удалось его найти. Был бы признателен если бы подсказали если возможность переопределить writer.output что бы исправить его поведение. Или может быть подскажите в каком моменте вызывается writer.output

Comment: Вот пока это единственное решение которое я смог найти https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325109/java-jtextpane-html-editor-utf-8-characters-encoding

Comment: Ну я думаю, они там пишут правду, насчёт того что это невозможно сделать с системным `HTMLWriter`. Но можно унаследоваться, переопределить `output`, написать свой `HTMLEditorKit` который будет использовать этого наследника итд